# Kentico CMSListMenu Styling each li

Tags: css, kentico

I have an html menu listing that look like this:

```
    <ul id="navlist" class="clearfix">
      <li class="home"><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li class="xo"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="xoxo"><a href="#">People</a></li>
      <li class="xoxoxo"><a href="#">Business</a></li>
      <li class="xo"><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li class="xoxo"><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
      <li class="xoxoxo"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li class="xi"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
```

My challenge is ensuring the CMSListMenu apply the different classes to each li.

Comment: http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums/f49/fp6/t15342/add-specific-class-to-css-list-menu-link-item.aspx

Comment: @Anon, thanks. I found my way around it. I used the document properties > navigation tab. It exposed the css for each document.

Answer (score 1):

The li could styled each by using Edit > Document Properties > Navigation tab provided in portal engine.

It exposed the css styling of each page li. You can set the link, mouseover and current page classes.